# How to export table definitions and data in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql workbench 6.3 and I can´t find a way to generate a sql file with one table definition and data.

I could find where to export data or table definition but not both.

Comment: Consider using a commandline and `mysqldump`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following window on **workbench.**
[image]